# How do you pass the page id of the current menu element to a user function?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm working on the following menu:

```
lib.content = HMENU
lib.content {
  special = directory
  special.value.data = page:id

  wrap   = <div id="productNavigator">|</div>
  expAll = 1

  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    noBlur = 1
    expAll = 1

    NO {
      stdWrap.cObject = COA
      stdWrap.cObject {

        10 = IMAGE
        10 {
          file {
            import.cObject = USER
            import.cObject {
              userFunc = tx_dam_pages->get_media_file
              uid      = ???
              listNum  = 0
              slide    = 1
            }
          }
        }

        30 = TEXT
        30.field = title
        30.wrap = <span class="text"><span>|</span></span>
      }
    }
```

The idea is to pull the DAM image assigned to the page into the menu. But I have no idea how to pass the id of the menu element into the user function.

If I add a constant value, it works great, every menu item gets the same image. But I want every menu item to have the image for the page it links to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

François Suter also provided this solution on the [TYPO3-english](http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-english/2012-July/081512.html) mailing list:

```
NO.before.cObject = IMAGE
NO.before.cObject.file.import.cObject = USER
NO.before.cObject.file.import.cObject {
    userFunc = tx_dam_tsfe->fetchFileList
    refTable = pages
    refField = tx_dampages_files
}
```

This works perfectly in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You get the uid of the page via `uid.field = uid`. In the rendering process, you have allways the page loaded, which gets rendered.

But i would not expect that `slide = 1` works. Does it?

```
    10 = IMAGE
    10 {
      file {
        import.cObject = USER
        import.cObject {
          userFunc = tx_dam_pages->get_media_file
          uid.field = uid
          listNum  = 0
          slide    = 1
        }
      }
    }
```

If that does not work, check if a static value for uid works.

Btw. did not know `tx_dam_pages->get_media_file` before. Is is shipped with DAM?

Comment: it's from `dam_pages` ext: http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/dam_pages/0.1.2/view/1/3/

Comment: @MarcusbiesiorBiesioroff: Exactly, that's where I copied this from. The solution seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: Okay, actually it doesn't work at all for me, I just forgot to comment out François' solution further down in the file...